# Sending an email (from Actions) to an individual hangs

Tags: email, activity

I hope I can get some light on this problem.  I am sending an email to an individual, not a mass email, just one email to an individual and when I click on send, it shows the system thinking but does not actually send the email and it just hangs in there forever.

I tried different emails and different subjects etc. and it always happens.  I recently changed servers and maybe I still have a setting that is not right, but mass emails are sent, when someone makes a contribution emails are sent, just not when it is an individual.  What could it be??

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you clarify your steps. Have you created a Group as a Mailing List that this single person is in, or are you doing it by some other method? In general 'recipients' requires you to choose a Group or Recipients of a previous mailing. Or are you doing this from the Search screen? Also do you want to explain why you would send a CiviMail to a single person rather than just send it as an Activity of type Email

Comment: Ok,  I maybe it is not CiviMail then.  I am trying to send an email to an indiviudal from their individual screen,  When you are in an individual,s record you can take an action, One of those actions is to send an email.  When I try to do that, the email never sends, and it looks like i get an endless loop where it just hangs there with the CiviCRM turning.

Comment: right, so no it is not 'civimail' and, when you click on 'send email' under 'actions' can you pls 'right click' and have it open in a new tab, that way hopefully when it fails you will get a more useful msg.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so when I do what you suggest, I get the following error
 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /administrator/ on this server.
Soemthing is messed up with my persmissions,

The error occurs when I hit send email

Comment: probably worth rewriting your ticket to include new info if you want folk to help you diagnose

Comment: Could you check your email settings in Administer>System Settings>Outbound Email.  Does the "Save and Send Test Email" actually work?

Comment: Yes, I have checked and that works